# mysql query not working in live server but working on local server

Tags: mysql, sql

I i want to take the results like bassed on today date.how many registration heppaned in today, i written the query in mysql it is woring fine in local server when ever going to live server not working properly

I have like this (task is tableNname)

```
id     taskName                    t_completed_on

1        Search Module             2017-03-14 06:50 AM
```

bassed on my table results(COUNT) will return 1,this my tried code.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `task` WHERE DATE(`t_completed_on`) = CURDATE() AND t_project!='Miscellaneous'
```

Same code working for my local xampp server,but not working in live server what is the issue please tell me anyone and update the answer.

Comment: Please add more detail on why the results are not what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Your local and live servers could be using different timezones